# CSV values into a span element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, csv

I have a `span` element in my HTML with the ID `info` and a .csv file formatted like this:

```
heading1,heading2,heading3,heading4,heading5
0,0,0,0,0
```

I want to have my `span` element display the result of adding all of my second row together, in this case 0.

I'm using jQuery and [jquery-csv](https://github.com/typeiii/jquery-csv) and have this code:

```
var data = $.csv.toArrays(file.csv);
var info = document.getElementById("info");

info.innerHTML = data[1,0] + data[1,1] + data[1,2] + data[1,3] + data[1,4];
```

This should add all of the second row together and show it in the `span` element, however it instead retains the placeholder value I put there (X).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is how you try to set the value

```js
$('#info').html(data[1,0] + data[1,1] + data[1,2] + data[1,3] + data[1,4]);
```